# Spark SQL regex to extract date, file name and brand

Tags: sql, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

Currently I have several files and I want to upload them to a DB, creating new columns with some metadata on them. An example of the files I have is the following:

```
MYBRAND-GOOD_20210202.tab
MYBRAND-BAD_20210202.tab
MYBRAND_20210202.tab
```

each file have x,y,z columns and additionally I want to create 3 new columns with metadata on them, based on some properties of the files. What I would like to have as a result is the following:

```
Table MYBRAND-GOOD

x | y  | z  | brand  | FILE_DATE  | SOURCE_DETAILS  | Name 
a.  b    c     GOOD      20210202       tab            MYBRAND-GOOD_20210202


Table MYBRAND-BAD

x | y  | z  | brand  | FILE_DATE  | SOURCE_DETAILS  | Name 
a.  b    c     BAD      20210202       tab            MYBRAND-BAD_20210202

Table MYBRAND

x | y  | z  | brand        | FILE_DATE  | SOURCE_DETAILS  | Name 
a.  b    c     MYBRAND      20210202       tab            MYBRAND_20210202
```

What I'm currently doing is the following :

```
SELECT x,y,z,
       split(INPUT_FILE_NAME(),'- | _')[1] AS brand,
       regexp_extract(INPUT_FILE_NAME(), '.*/modified_dttm=(.*)/.+', 1) AS FILE_DATE,
       regexp_extract(regexp_replace(INPUT_FILE_NAME()\\,'%20'\\,'')\\, '.*/.*-([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).tab'\\, 1)) AS SOURCE_DETAILS
       regexp_extract(INPUT_FILE_NAME(), '^([^\.]+)\.?', 0) AS NAME
```

However I'm facing several problems (since I'm not very proficient with regex):

- brand fails if it doesn't have a '-' separator (AS in 'MYBRAND')
- I'm not sure if 'FILE_DATE' it's doing what's suppose to do
- SOURCE_DETAILS is giving me empty results
- NAME is ok, but I would like to exclude the '.'

If someone could guide me with this regex rules, which I don't follow completely, I would appreciate any correction.

Answer (score 0):

We can write one pattern for the whole string and vary the index argument of regexp_extract() for each desired element.

```
(Mybrand(-([A-Za-z0-9]*))?_(\d{8,8}))\.(\w+)
```

Using that pattern each time, you can select which capture group to display

```
Select x,y,z
   Regexp_extract(INPUT_FILE_NAME(),'(Mybrand(-([A-Za-z0-9]*))?_(\d{8,8}))\.(\w+)', 3) AS Brand,
   Regexp_extract(INPUT_FILE_NAME(),'(Mybrand(-([A-Za-z0-9]*))?_(\d{8,8}))\.(\w+)', 4) AS FileDate,
   Regexp_extract(INPUT_FILE_NAME(),'(Mybrand(-([A-Za-z0-9]*))?_(\d{8,8}))\.(\w+)', 5) AS SourceDetails,
   Regexp_extract(INPUT_FILE_NAME(),'(Mybrand(-([A-Za-z0-9]*))?_(\d{8,8}))\.(\w+)', 1) AS Name
```

You parenthesize each subpattern you want to capture, so we start with a parenthesis pair right at the beginning to capture the name.  Then we scan MYBRAND, then start a new parenthesis group because the hyphen is optional.  Then we start the third parenthesis group to capture the alphanumerics [A-Za-z0-9]* which make up the brand.  The star lets the group be empty which will retrieve a null. Next comes an underscore followed by a new set of parens to capture the digits making up the date \d{8,8}.  We close the first parenthesis here to end the file name capture, then a dot, and the final parens to capture the filetype (\w+).